# Can enter key act like tab key when picking tags

Tags: feature-request

When I enter a tag on any of the sites if the returned result is one tag and I hit enter shouldn't it act like pressing the tab key?  Feature request!!  I'd like to be able to hit the enter key when I select tags as long as there is one tag coming up.

For instance, If I type **jobs** in the tag field it comes up with one tag.  If I hit enter (which to me seems natural) it doesn't do anything unless you mouse it or use the tab key.

Comment: Wow I got tumbleweed badge for this!

Comment: @Arun I don't think this needs the discussion tag. It's a feature-request plain and simple...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan agreed. it will help to bump this up.. :)

Comment: That is not an appropriate use of editing. See [this Q&A on the uber meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125965/194720).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan but we have archeologist batch for editing/cleaning up post older than 6 months. Moreover the post you shared is irrelevant. I thought of asking this feature, since I noticed the dupe without votes & status update of this low hanging fruit, hence put under discussion so it may atleast get triaged.. never mind someone removed the discussion tag.

Comment: @ArunVinoth From the "irrelevant" post's [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125967/194720) by [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/153008/cody-gray), a [moderator on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray): ""Bumping" old questions is perfectly acceptable, and even *encouraged*, **when you have something new to contribute.**" (emphasis in the original). You did not contribute anything new to this post. Therefore, it is not an appropriate bump. There is an appropriate way of drawing attention to old questions: the bounty system. Feel free to use that.